# Installing git repository on Oracle Enterprise Linux 5 -- SSH problems

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitosis, rhel5

I have been banging my head against a wall for a while now, and none of the people in my immediate vicinity know more than I do at this point.

My office has a lab box that they want to use for a central git repository -- mainly for testing various things.  They also, of course, want me to get some experience setting up git so that we can possibly set up other git instances later.

I am running Windows 7 with an OEL 5.7 VM, and the box is running OEL 5.5.  From my VM, I SSHed into the lab box and started tinkering.  After installing git and gitosis, I have managed to get the instance working locally.  I can see the git repository just fine, and if I try to clone it locally, it all works like a dream.  But if I try to SSH in from my VM, it either A.) kicks me out with `fatal: 'testproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository` or B.) kicks me out with `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)`, depending on how I invoke git.

Example: I configured the access to a test project I created (and tested locally) as follows:

```
[group team]
writable = testproject
members = oracle@RCSDB cwerness cwerness@localhost cwerness@localhost.localdomain
```

This is my first experience setting up a git repository, so I wanted to cover my bases regarding remote users.  Thus, the redundancy in the members section.

When I try to clone the repository with my username only, I get

```
[cwerness@localhost Desktop]$ git clone cwerness@10.1.1.10:testproject.git
Cloning into testproject...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/cwerness/.ssh/id_rsa': 
fatal: 'testproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If, however, I try to clone the repository with more information, I get

```
[cwerness@localhost Desktop]$ git clone "cwerness@localhost.localdomain"@10.1.1.10:testproject.git
Cloning into testproject...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have all the public keys stored in the /keydir folders.  The repository was created and is owned by the user `oracle`, and I have tried all permutations of that user and its domain in the above clone commands as well, to no effect.  Additionally, I tried setting up a ~/.ssh/config file like this

```
Host labbox
    Hostname 10.1.1.10
    User cwerness
    IdentityFile /home/cwerness/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Again, I tried all the different ways to connect, from both users.  Nothing is giving me any more information than I already had.

The box is set up to authenticate SSH connections via public keys, and that works fine.  I can SSH into the box as `cwerness` with no problems.

This is getting to be a huge headache for me, and I'd like it if someone could tell me exactly HOW I am being stupid, if not a way to fix this problem.

Comment: try: git clone git://cwerness@10.1.1.10:testporoject.git

Comment: gitosis was replaced by gitolite long ago

Comment: git// doesn't work at all, and the repository exists in /home/oracle/repositories/

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -al ~/testproject.git` on your lab box? That may help us determine why Git thinks there is no repository there.

Answer (score 2):

`git clone cwerness@10.1.1.10:testproject.git` will look in the home directory for the user `cwerness` but you state you put the repository in `/home/oracle/repositories`.  Try `git clone cwerness@10.1.1.10:/home/oracle/repositories/testproject.git`.